# Basic Azure Integrated AD Authentication

Tags: asp.net, azure, owin, azure-active-directory, asp.net-4.5

There are a million tutorials on this, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have VS 2015 with an OWIN middleware ASP .NET website running in IISExpress. Disabled Windows auth and enabled anonymous. Right clicked "Configure Azure AD Authentication" on the web project. Went through the wizard, entered domain name and app url. It navigated to a login page and seemed to install fine.

I now have a call to UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication in my startup. However, in IE, which should be using integrated authentication (it does for my Office365 account on the same domain), calling my WebAPI urls via GET yields 401 errors. Additionally, if I add some middleware and put a breakpoint, I see that the Thread.CurrentPrincipal is Anonymous. Is there something I need to do in my html/javscript client app to bootstrap the authentication? If so, what?

Comment: You require Azure AD authentication on the server, correct? How do you authenticate on the client? Are you using ADAL? `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` will force the app to look for a Bearer token in requests and to validate it with Azure AD.

Comment: Yes I'm using ADAL. I think I at least understand the problem - JavaScript is getting back an id token but not an access token. Even if I call acquireToken passing in the resource id as the ida:Audience from my WebAPI, I don't get back an access token (I get a type of UKNOWN).

Comment: Is your website a Single Page Application or Standard MVC?
There are good examples for each of the use cases at https://github.com/AzureADSamples